# What are the bombshelters for in Singapore?

Tags: housing, singapore

I noticed that all condos have bunkers in Singapore. It's apparantly also a building regulation to have a bunker in newly build condos. I'm just unsure what the incentive was to create this regulation in the first place? What is it that they are supposed to protect you from?

Singapore is very peaceful (last invasion dates back to the Japanese during WWII, not counting the failed Indonesian bombings) so I'm actually curious about this one considering we have one and so do all other expats I know.

Comment: Are you sure they're bomb shelters? And not, say, typhoon shelters?

Comment: There are similar regulations in Switzerland, another peaceful country which hasn't taken part in a war in ages and wasn't even invaded during WWII. Cold war and location could be an argument in the case of Swizerland but maybe bomb shelters are especially appealing to neutral/small/peaceful countries? In terms of building regulations and cultural impact, 1965 is not that far back, incidentally, those things change slowly…

Comment: In any case, I think the question is more a “curiosity” question about a country in general than a genuine expatriation-related practical question so I am inclined to consider it off-topic for this site. Maybe history.SE would be more appropriate?

Comment: http://history.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate, yes

Comment: Those are definitely meant for war, as their [official website](http://www.scdf.gov.sg/content/scdf_internet/en/building-professionals/cd-shelter/shelter-programme.html) states. For HDB flats, every flat has one (I never quite understood the utility of a shelter on the 40th floor) and if you pay attention, you'll notice that a lot of the MRT stations double as shelter (they have a yellow sign and you can see movable walls, here's the [list](http://www.scdf.gov.sg/content/scdf_internet/en/building-professionals/cd-shelter/public-shelters.html))

Comment: I believe this would be on-topic at travel.SE, wouldn't it?

Comment: My above link is dead. This is the [current link to the official website](http://www.scdf.gov.sg/content/scdf_internet/en/building-professionals/cd-shelter.html).

Comment: @Gagravarr, Is it even geologically possible to have a typhoon in Singapore?

Comment: @drat "*never quite understood the utility of a shelter on the 40th floor*".  Neither did New York City's Giuliani, whose Office for Emergency Management, from which the Mayor would direct operations in a large scale emergency, was located in a "bunker" on the 23ʳᵈ floor of World Trade Center 7, making it rather useless when it was actually needed.